# DCOM: How to allow access to all remote users

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machines, remote-access, dcom

We are create virtual machine instances which will host our app server. These are run on our laptops for demo

Our app server uses DCOM to perform remote authentication/access to services. I want to enable access to any and every user so that these instances can be used by any number of current and future employees.

To do this, I want to enable access to all remote users on this VM instance for certain DCOM services.

The options I have tried

- I have added remote access and launch permission to Everyone usergroup
- I have added remote access and launch permission to Anonymous logon user
- I have enabled "Network Access: Let Everyone permission apply to Anonymous users" option in Local security policy

Still the remote access is being denied.

Is there a way I can enable this access to any and every user who accesses this VM instance remotely?

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson!

Comment: are you just talking about doing this just for the demo laptops?

Comment: Yes only for demo laptops and never exposed to any machine other than host laptop.